# Pinescript: forcing a variable to take an integer value

Tags: int, rounding, pine-script

Code looks something like this:

```
vol = stdev(returns, 21)
weight = int(1 / vol)
```

I then try to call the function `highest(source, length)` where the length of the series is determined by the weight variable but I get the error message "Cannot call 'highest' with arguments (series[float], series[integer]); available overloads: highest(series[float], integer) => series[float]; highest(integer) => series[float]".

Same issue if I use `round(x)` rather than `int(x)` (or `int(round(x)))` or `round(int(x))`). However, `highest(source, int(21.41))`, for example, works.

How can I get Pinescript to run `highest(source, weight)`?!

Answer (score 0):

According to TradingView support, the length argument in `highest(source, length)` cannot vary, i.e. it is not really an `int` but a `const int`.